# Send single mail to reciever if 6 messages are send within 10 minutes in wordpress or php

Tags: php, wordpress, email, plugins, chat

I want to set up my chat system so that if a user sends 6 messages within 10 minutes time frame, then send a single mail with all the 6 messages. If it is less  than 6 messages then send mail for each messages in wordpress or core php. I do not have any idea about how to do this in either wordpress or core php. Please some one who has any idea about this please let me know here.

Comment: Do already have some code which sends the single emails? It's not clear. But that would be a good starting point. Also what exactly are you stuck with? Have you tried to break the problem down, or come up with any rough design? Is it writing the code which is the issue, or how to design it, or how to calculate the time windows, or what? Your question is pretty vague, it needs to be more specific.

Comment: @ADyson This is the requirement and i already have a mail code that sends each chat message to the reciever via email also. But I want to optimize my email function so that it will send all the 6 messages which are typed within the 10 minutes time frame in one mail instead of 6 mails.

Comment: Ok. So again...where are you stuck?

Comment: @ADyson I don't know how to hold the typed message and calculate the time frame.

Comment: You probably need to save the messages in a database and then have a Cron job to send out all recent messages at timed intervals